# List of available Rails http headers (like ":success", ":created", and ":bad_request"). Where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-headers

You can [use `head` to build header-only responses](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses). The Rails guide is very helpful in pointing out that you can send a `:bad_request` or `:created` header. Where is a list of all of these Rails HTTP header aliases?

Comment: These are status codes, not headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L402), it's used by Rails to set the status codes. To have the symbol, just "downcase" and "underscore" the hash values.

Comment: +1 for source, you can also get a link to the exact line by clicking on the line # in Github.

Comment: Perfect! I actually dug around in both the Rails and Rack source for a little while, but wasn't sure where to look. Thanks! (I edited your answer to link directly to the line number, as Beerlington suggested, for the sake of future readers.)

Comment: More info here: http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/7/4/rails-http-status-code-to-symbol-mapping